# wp_remote_get() and javascript/noscript situation

Tags: parameter, wp-remote-get

I am using `wp_remote_get()` to get access to certain pages on the net. However, when I make a call using `wp_remote_get()`, the response I recieve is a webpage that contains the following lines of code:

```
<body>
    <noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
```

So, the page is not returning in full because of the way it is programmed. Is there a way to change the call so that the **non-noscript** page returns instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is expected since `wp_get_remote()` doesn't include a Javascript engine.

It should give you the same result as the *View Source* option in your browser and fetch the plain HTML document.

It looks like the page your are trying to fetch, is loading a Javascript file, in the header tag, to render the content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/load-content.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>Your browser doesn't support Javascript!</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

So you should get both the `script` and the `noscript` part.

What you are looking for is called *headless browsing*.

If you want to run the Javascript, you might want to take a look at solutions like: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API.
>
> [...] One major use case of PhantomJS is headless testing of web
>   applications. It is suitable for general command-line based testing,
>   within a precommit hook, and as part of a continuous integration
>   system.

There exists many test frameworks for *PhantomJS*, like *Jasmine*, *Mocha* and *QUnit*.

**Alternatively**: Try to load the Javascript file with `wp_remote_get()` and see if you can extract the content that way ;-)

Comment: Couple that with CapserJS and you have some real power at your hands. That aside, wouldn't setting the user-agent property of the args parameter on [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments) be enough to have the page serve up its JS?

Comment: @userabuser great suggestion regarding CasperJS. I think `wp_get_remote()` will just serve the plain HTML, like the "View Source" in the browser. So you will get both the script and noscript tags, regardless of the *user-agent* string in the header.